# xfce4-notes: Toggle notes visibility via keyboard shortcut

Tags: xfce, notes

I use `xfce4-notes` in Xubuntu 14.04, und I have the possibility to show/hide the notes via the panel plugin in the notification tray. I will append images of this panel plugin because I can not find its exact name:

[image]

[image: icon2]

Every click on one of the icons toggles the visibility --- shows or hides the notes.

Now I would love to do that by keyboard shortcut. For that I need the command the panel buttons call. My Google-Fu failed me in that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 7):

Well there is `xfce4-popup-notes` that can make notes visible but does not toggle it! Although you have to use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to hide it again!

Comment: Did not know this command, and also not that I can use Esc key. Thanks! Although a "real" toggle command would be nicer e.g. because of multiple notes groups.

Comment: FYI: I noticed that you can cycle through all note groups (concerning window focus) when repeatedly pressing the shortcut for xfce4-popup-notes.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the tab view from the properties dialog in xfce4-notes (right-click on title bar). Then use `Tab + Ctrl` key combination to select the current tab. After that, use `Left and Right Arrow` keys to switch in between tabs.

Also, you can use `Ctrl + N` keys to create a new note. `Esc` key to hide the window.